# Compound interest script not work properly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I did not get the right solution. My problem is php compound interest. Compound interest is like this Monthly pay 100, interest rate 0.08%, compound frequency 12 per year, time 60 month.

After 60 months, capital will be 6000 and profit will be 1322 and total 7322.

```
public function monthcount($date1){

  $begin = new DateTime($date1);
  $date2 = date("d M Y"); 
  $end   = new DateTime($date2);
  $end   = $end->modify( ' -1 month ' );

  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString( ' 1 month ' );
  $period   = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

  $counter  = 0;
  foreach ($period as $dt){
    $counter++;  
  }
  return $counter;
}

public function compinterest($p){

 $r  = 0.08;    
 $n = 12; 
 $t = 1/12;
 $c = $r/$n;

 $p1 = $p*pow(1+$c, $t*$n);
 $in1 = $p1-$p;       
 return $in1;   
 }

$starting   = date( "d M Y", strtotime( "01-04-2013" ));
$getmont    = $com->monthcount($starting, $ending);
$p          = 6000;
$monthlypay = 100;
$in         = 0;
for($i=1;  $i<=$getmont; $i++){
$value = $com->compinterest($p);
$in += $value;
$val= $in+$p;

echo $i."Total".$val;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here instead of adding screenshot of the code

Comment: I think your calculations are wrong. Your currentBalance never changes, that means that during your 60 iterations $value is always the same (0.666...) so that $in becomes 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if your math functions may be the problem, I am not sure if the answer I have given is what you are trying to accomplish. To complete the code I would be helpful to know if this is the right direction.

```
$x = .08;
$y = 12;
$z = $x/$y;

$a= ($z+1);
$b=100;
$c=$a*$b;

// $c 1st month plus interest //
$d=($b+$c)*$a;

// $d 2nd month plus interest //
$e=($b+$d)*$a;


echo $c;
echo "\n";
echo $d;
echo "\n";
echo $e;
```

Comment: How to use it for loop?